# TYPO3 Flow Dependency Injection and geting objects that are sub objects of others

Tags: dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, typo3, typo3-flow

Hello I have been learning to use FLOW and have some questions:

I have an action in a controller like this:

```
/**
 * Displays a subproduct.
 *
 * @param \My\Package\Domain\Model\Product $product The main product.
 * @param \My\Package\Domain\Model\Subproduct $subProduct A sub-product of $product.
 * @return void
 */
public function subproductAction(\My\Package\Domain\Model\Product $product, \My\Package\Domain\Model\Subproduct $subProduct) {
    $this->view->assign('product', $product);
    $this->view->assign('subProduct', $subProduct);
}
```

This was fine for testing and learning about the framework, but now I want to make sure that $subProduct is actually a sub-product of $product.

What would be the best way of doing this?

- Use DI (like it now is) to get both the product and subproduct and check if $product
  contains $subProduct, if not alter what variables I assign to my
  view? Or:
- Inject the product and use to some method of $product    to
  return the $subproduct, if it is a sub-product of product.
- Create a repo function that gets the subproduct if it's product
  column is the product?

Products can contain hundreads of subproducts and for my application I only need to get one subproduct and display that, so I can't just use my products getSubProducts() method as this would return all of them.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1):

I know it is old question, but there is nothing about dependency injection.

In your `\My\Package\Domain\Model\Product` you should have field `protected $subProducts` of type `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection<My\Package\Domain\Model\Subproduct>` with `setsubProducts`, `getSubProducts` and maybe `addSubProduct` (get + add) methods inside.

It is collection so you can use `contains`, `add` and so on.

Now when you have product assigned to view in your controller - in fluid sth like `{product}` - you can use fluid `for` view helper on `{product.subProducts}` - there is no need to get it in controller (all get [and some other] public methods from Model works that way).

Just for validation (on update) you can check if `$product->getSubProducts->contains($subProduct)` then something..

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first approach. Let the framework give you the entities and check in your action if the $subProduct actually belongs to the $product.

From my experience it's often the best to go with the simple approach.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here but if you only want to display the $subProduct why no DI the $subProduct and use it's relation to the product in the template? I mean the $subProduct has to have some inverse relation to the product right?

So, your action would look like this:

```
/**
 * Displays a subproduct.
 *
 * @param \My\Package\Domain\Model\Subproduct $subProduct A sub-product of $product.
 * @return void
 */
public function subproductAction(\My\Package\Domain\Model\Subproduct $subProduct) {
    $this->view->assign('subProduct', $subProduct);
}
```

and in your template you could do something like:

```
 {subProduct.product.title}
```

I hope this helps. To give a decent advice it would be necessary to know you whole application or at least one needs a besser understanding of the problem.